# MAVEN MojoExecutionException al guardar con JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa utilizando Maven conjuntamente con JPA así como Hibernate, al intentar hacer una prueba de las clases que tengo para manejo de objetos me salta el siguiente error y no me permite hacer ninguna operación:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project Agenda: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Este es un ejemplo del código que utilizo para guardar:

```
public class Agenda_IMPL{

EntityManagerFactory emf= Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.agenda_jar_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU");
EntityManager em= emf.createEntityManager();

public void guardar(Contacto p) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    try {
        em.persist(p);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    em.clear();
  }
}
```

También para introducir los datos utilizo esta clase:

```
public class AgendaTest {

  Agenda_IMPL agenda= new Agenda_IMPL();
  contacto con= new contacto();

  public void guardar(){

    con.setNombre("José");
    con.setApellido("García");
    con.setTelefono(8095556666);

    agenda.guardar(con);
}

  public static void main(String[] args){
    AgendaTest agendac= new AgendaTest();
    agendac.guardar();

  }
}
```

Este Este es el pom.xml del proyecto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.agenda</groupId>
<artifactId>Agenda</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<name>Agenda</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.13.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Aunque no se porqué pero al hacer `mvn e- package` me dice que no tengo la variable **JAVA_HOME** declarada, sin embargo si la tengo declara
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y si haces `mvn -e package` para que salgan los detalles?

Comment: Me da este **Warning** amigo `JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.` pero no se porque si tengo la variable declarada en el sistema

Answer (score 0):

Lo que me funcionó, es igualar la versión del JDK instalado en mi equipo
[image: version jdk en equipo intalado]

con la que se construyó el proyecto, la cual la puedes visualizar en el archivo pom.xml

```
...
        <properties>
            <java.version>17</java.version>
        </properties> 
...
```